# Install CentOS 7 without any local disk?

Tags: centos, system-installation, iscsi, san

If we only got disks from iSCSI (additionally multipath) and no local disks, how can we install a CentOS 7 on them?

Answer (score 0):

This article describes how to do so with GUI installer.

http://etherboot.org/wiki/sanboot/centos_iscsi_install